# How to install newest version of Texmaker on 12.10

Tags: installation, libraries

The software repo in Quantal has version 3.2.1 of texmaker, but texmaker is now up to version 3.5. I would like to have version 3.5.

After downloading the `.deb` from the website (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html, Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 package) and trying to install it, it complains about wanting `libpoppler-qt4-4`.

I can't find `libpoppler-qt4-4` in the repos, only `libpoppler-qt4-3`. How can I install texmaxer 3.5?

Comment: [**Latest version**](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)  Version **4.0.1** : March 16 **2013**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions of the software you mention (`Texmaker 3.2.1` and `libpoppler-qt4-3`) are those included in the **Precise** repositories. However, `libpoppler-qt4-4` and `Texmaker 3.4-1` are in the **Quantal** repositories and are listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libpoppler-qt4-4) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texmaker).

I should check whether you have upgraded properly and run `sudo apt-get update` to refresh your lists.

However, you can check the *Software Sources* gui (for example by going to update manager's settings) and see which repositories you are subscribed to, or perhaps edit your `sources.list` (see below), if inconsistencies have crept into it.

**Note** (for later readers): you should only carry out the following commands if you have upgraded successfully and are on 12.10.

So, at first open terminal and enter

```
cd /etc/apt
```

and then run

```
sudo sed -i 's/precise/quantal/g' *.list
```

That should change any erroneous instances of `precise` to `quantal`.

(If you wish, you can inspect it manually with `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`)

Now run `sudo apt-get update` and you should be using the quantal repositories and thus able to install `libpoppler-qt4-4` and everything else you want.

Comment: I can't believe this. I thought I installed 12.10 on Thursday, but I'm running 12.04! I must have picked the wrong .iso file when I made my boot stick. This is ridiculous. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah I see now- glad to help.